# GAE Datastore: put into a field using a string as the field reference python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am reading a CSV file from a web source and would like to store it in my GAE datastore. The CSV data comes with a header row, that with a bit of manipulation will match the fields in my datastore (eg. replace spaces from CSV file with underscore to match datastore). I would like to just iterate through the fields in each line of the CSV file and put them into the datastore.

My question is how do I reference a field in the datastore with a string and set its value to another string?

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
from urllib import urlopen
from csv import DictReader

class Table(db.Model):
    field_one = db.StringProperty() # equivalent to 'field one' column in CSV data
    field_two = db.StringProperty() # equivalent to 'field two' column in CSV data

def store_csv_data(url):
    # Request the url with the csv data
    f = urlopen(url)
    csv_dict = DictReader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for line in csv_dict:
        # Do some processing on the data (not shown here)
        row = Table()
        for field in line:
            db_field = field.replace(' ','_') # Make the csv field match the db field
            db_value = line[field] # The value I want to store in the datastore
            row.db_field = db_value # THIS IS WHERE THE CODE FAILS
        row.put()
```

This does not actually generate any errors, it just creates a bunch of empty rows in the datastore.

Comment: What error are you getting? That would really help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
setattr(row, db_field, db_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing your problem is on this line:

```
db_value = line[field]
```

should be:

```
db_value = field[0]
```

You will have to replace the Zero with the field column number so going with your above example of:

```
class Table(db.Model):
    field_one = db.StringProperty()
    field_two = db.StringProperty()
```

field_one would be 0 and field_2 would be 1